# Serial Communication in Unity

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine, serial-port, frame-rate

I have unity3d game and plugged Gyroscope with serial port (using RS232).

I am reading Gyroscope data from `Update()` function, the problem is, I wait for total Serial data package to be received in the unity application using `myPort.ReadLine()`. Since gyroscope is sending values slowly (with delays), it takes time to receive total data, therefore my framerate drops below 20FPS.

What can I do to run Serial reading function independently from the game logic, so that they don't interfere?

(InvokeRepeating doesn't work because when the script is waiting for serial data, it isn't doing any game logic at all).

Comment: Run it in a Task or separate thread.

Comment: Could you give me more information about Task and/or separate thread, as I have no idea what they do. Tutorial reference would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx is a good start, Google is the next step, use something like *C# Task Tutorial* as keywords.

Comment: Sorry, Unity's c# does not support Tasks (no System.Threading.Tasks)

Comment: Sorry, forgot Unity runs on Mono, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx instead, and follow up with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472947/help-me-find-some-good-c-sharp-threading-tutorials